# If statement causes: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators

I am trying to randomly select an option using `Math.random()`
This is the code I have so far.

```js
function randChoice() {
 var chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  if (chance > -1 && < 50) {
    console.log("Option 1"); // 1
  } else if (crateId > 49 && < 71) {
    console.log("Option 2"); // 2
  } else if (crateId > 70 && < 91) {
    console.log("Option 3"); // 3
  }
}
```

When I run it, I get an error saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

What is wrong with my syntax? I've been looking for at least an hour, but I can't find anything that will help or any indication of what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `crateId > 49 && < 71` is not valid syntax.

There needs to be either a variable name or a literal between any two binary operators, only unary operators may be adjacent.

It needs to be: `crateId > 49 && crateId < 71`.